# How to vibrate an object with Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to simulate a very simple earthquake with Unity. The main idea is to move the platform backward/forward. I tried the code below but it did not work. I need something similar to that.

```
transform.position += transform.forward*10;
transform.position += transform.forward*-10;
```

Comment: If you do the above, it happens before Unity processes the physics/render step so the platform doesn't actually move. Look at the `FixedUpdate()` method. You also need to consider that if you do this so quickly it might look a bit jarring to the eye - I'd recommend doing it over several fixed steps. I believe the default is 50 updates per second, so you might want to move every 2/3 fixed updates instead of every update. You could also use an easing function - a parametric one might make the vibration look more realistic and it's pretty simple to do.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html here's the docs on `FixedUpdate`. Some hints - create 2 `Vector3s` that represent the min/max position of the vibration which are an offset from the original position which you should also store. You can then interpolate between min/max and add that result to `transform.position` in `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: The reason why your code doesn't work is: It does both calculations within the same frame so in the end it just ends up at the same position ^^ You would have to wait between both operations. anyway such a huge jump about 10 units would look pretty odd and you should rather move the object smooth but fast (e.g. Coroutine) .. and also probably a bit randomized to make it look more natural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do this over multiple updates so that each difference can be rendered to the screen, something like this I'd recommend

```
private Vector3 initialPosition;
Vector3 directionOfShake = transform.forward;
public float amplitude; // the amount it moves
public float frequency; // the period of the earthquake

void Start(){
    initialPosition; = transform.position // store this to avoid floating point error drift
}



void FixedUpdate(){
     transform.position = initialPosition + directionOfShake*Mathf.Sin(frequency * Time.FixedDeltaTime)*amplitude;
}
```

This allows you to alter the earthquake from the editor.

Or if you want something sharper

```
void FixedUpdate(){
         transform.position = initialPosition + directionOfShake*(-amplitude + Mathf.PingPong(frequency * Time.FixedDeltaTime, 2.f*amplitude);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an earthquake the best way is you shake the camera and not the platform.

To do that you can use the [EZ Camera Shake Unity Asset](https://github.com/andersonaddo/EZ-Camera-Shake-Unity/tree/master/Assets) (was deleted form the assets store so here is a link to GitHub).

If you do choose to move the platform anyway you can still use the asset's scripts on your platform.

To learn more about how to use this asset just look '*EZ Camera Shake Unity*' on YouTube